# C - argv stores random values instead of given ones

Tags: c, command-line, argv

The program should take three command line arguments of which the first is an arithmetical operand and the second and third numbers on which the operand should be applied
This program will print random values.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, int *argv[])
{
  switch ( (char) * argv[1] )
  {
    case '+' : printf("%d", *argv[2] + *argv[3] );
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Also, how am I supposed to get as command line arguments different data types? Is using the type cast correct?

Comment: `int *argv[]` ==> `char *argv[]`.

Comment: `int main (int argc, int *argv[])` --->  `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`

Comment: `%d` format specifier prints numbers, while `argv[x]` are strings....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if ( argc > 3 )
  {
    switch ( *argv[1] )
    {
       case '+' : 
          printf("answer: %d\n", atoi(argv[2]) + atoi(argv[3])  );
          break;
       default :
          printf("ERROR: operand %c invalid\n",*argv[1]);
    }
  }
  else 
  {
     printf("ERROR: you must enter operator, plus two operands. e.g.:\n");
     printf("%s + 3 2\n",argv[0]);
     return 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about that "atoi" function

Comment: [strtol](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) provides is more flexibility, as it can actually tell you if the whole string was converted to an integer or not

Comment: @LPs You need to convert the C-strings to integer so they can be added. Then the integer result is printed.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if(argc != 4) {
    printf("Error message");
    printf("USAGE: ./a.out <operand> <number1> <number2>");
    return 0;
  }
  switch(*argv[1]) {
    case '+':
      printf("%d", (atoi(argv[2])+atoi(argv[3])));
      break;
    default:
      printf("Enter valid operand");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, the arguments are read as an array of strings into `argv`. Thus you must use `char *argv[]`. Conversion from string to int is performed by `atoi`. Simply casting a character to an integer will give you the ASCII representation of that character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    switch ( *argv[1] )
    {
        case '+':
            printf("%d\n", atoi(argv[2]) + atoi(argv[3]) );
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

To get floating point arithmetic, replace `%d` with `%f` and `atoi` by `atof`.

Of course you should also add sanity checks. In the very minimum, you should check `argc` to prevent reading from uninitialized space. See comments.

Comment: I told to replace `int *argv[]` by `char *argv[]` but obviusly forgot to do so in my own example. Obviously I deserved the -1. Corrected.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but you **must** check `argc`  value before to access `argv` elements: otherwise `UB` is near the corner....

Comment: I guess you should also `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: @LPs what is `UB`?

Comment: @Tom [Undefined_behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: @LPs You are absolutely right! I didn't include it because I wanted to only answer OPs question. Checking the validity of the arguments is in my opinion another topic which I didn't want to delve into. One could (and probably should) test whether the arguments actually are numbers, that the operator is valid, etc. However, avoiding uninitialized memory by checking `argc` is the very minimum one should do. I added a comment about it.